# iptabels firewall rules for INPUT while Tor traffic on lubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: networking, lubuntu, iptables, firewall, tor

i do have lubuntu 22.04 LTS and TOR daemon with the torrc config

```
VirtualAddrNetwork 10.192.0.0/10
AutomapHostsOnResolve 1
TransPort 9040
DNSPort 9053
```

and iptables rules

```
#exclude locals
TOR_EXCLUDE="192.168.0.0/16 172.16.0.0/12 10.0.0.0/8"

#tor uid
TOR_UID="debian-tor"

#tor socks port
TOR_PORT="9040"

#tor dns port
TOR_DNS="9053"


iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F


iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP


#set iptables nat
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner $TOR_UID -j RETURN
#set dns redirect
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT --to-ports $TOR_DNS
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT --to-ports $TOR_DNS
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p udp -m owner --uid-owner $TOR_UID -m udp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT --to-ports $TOR_DNS


#exclude locals
for NET in $TOR_EXCLUDE 127.0.0.0/9 127.128.0.0/10; do
  iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d $NET -j RETURN
  iptables -A OUTPUT -d "$NET" -j ACCEPT
done

for NET in $TOR_EXCLUDE 127.0.0.0/8; do
iptables -A OUTPUT -d $NET -j ACCEPT
done


# redirect all other output through tor
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --syn -j REDIRECT --to-ports $TOR_PORT
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p udp -j REDIRECT --to-ports $TOR_PORT
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p icmp -j REDIRECT --to-ports $TOR_PORT


# allow only tor output
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner $TOR_UID -j ACCEPT


# accept already established connections
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
#iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT                                 
#iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

so the problem is with the last 2 rules

```
#iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
#iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

none of the rules work so the input traffic cannot be accepted, thats was found by  changing the default INPUT rule from **DROP** to **ACCEPT** everything, that is insecure

cant really understand the problem and the solution

and also the #exclude locals part makes me confuse with those 2 conditions

thanks

Comment: Also asked at https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/problem-with-iptabels-firewall-rules-for-input-while-tor-traffic-on-lubuntu-22-04-lts/3940/